# How to show or hide a view upon RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-coordinatorlayout

There is a plenty of answers related with `CoordinatorLayout` and `FAB`, however sometimes you just need to show / hide your custom view upon scroll down / up events from `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` to your recyclerview.

This solution is quite straightforward and works quite decent, plus you can adjust length of scroll to be ignored via `threshold` property, which is a  percentage of RCV height.

```
fun RecyclerView.hideShowScrollListener(view: View, threshold: Double = .5) {
    this.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            val thresholdValue = (recyclerView?.height ?: 0) / 100 * threshold
            if (dy > thresholdValue && view.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                view.gone()
            } else if (dy < -thresholdValue && view.visibility != View.VISIBLE) {
                view.visible()
            }
        }
    })
}
```